# Identify a FK which has the highest value from a list of values in its source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following tables.

Part

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Part 1 |
| 2 | Part 2 |
| 3 | Part 3 |

Operation

| id | name | part_id | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Op 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | Op 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | Op 3 | 1 | 30 |
| 4 | Op 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 5 | Op 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 6 | Op 1 | 3 | 10 |

Lot

| id | part_id | Operation_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 |
| 12 | 3 | 6 |

I am selecting the results from Lot table and I want to select a column `last_Op` which is based on the `order` value of the `operation_id`. If value of `order` for the `operation_id` is the highest for the respective `part_id`, return `1` else return `0`

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  part_id, 
  operation_id,
  last_Op
FROM Lot
```

expected result set based on the tables above.

| id | part_id | operation_id | last_op |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 12 | 3 | 6 | 1 |

In above example, first row returns last_op = `0` because operation_id = 2 is associated with `part_id` = 1 and it has the highest `order` = 30. Since `operation_id` for this part is not pointing towards the highest `order` value, `0` is returned.

The other two rows return 1 because `operation_id` 5 and 6 are associated with `part_id` 2 and 3 respectively and they are pointing towards the highest 'order' value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If value of order for the operation_id is the highest for the respective part_id, return 1 else return 0

This sounds like window functions will help:

```
select l.*,
       (case when o.order = o.max_order then 1 else 0 end) as last_op
from lot l left join
     (select o.*,
             max(o.order) over (partition by o.part_id) as max_order
      from operations o
     ) o
     on l.operation_id = o.id;
```

Note:  `order` is a very poor name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.